# What is the best way to extract widgets to create your own configuration?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

So let's say I want to have the same or very similar `AppBar` in a lot of screens.

To reduce duplicated code for most cases I would create a new widget that has the layout/configuration that I want. In this case it would look like this:

```dart
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyAppBar({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  void handlePress(){
    // handle press
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(title),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(onPressed: handlePress, icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

However, if I try to use this in a `Scaffold` I get the following error:

```
The argument type 'MyAppBar' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'
```

I have seen in [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61451762/13280594) that people extend the widget in question like this:

```dart
class IAppBar extends AppBar {
  final String label;

  IAppBar({super.key, required this.label})
      : super(
          title: Text(label),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: handlePress,
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            ),
          ],
        );

  void handlePress() {
    // handle press
  }
}
```

This is very clean and simple, but this produces the following error:

```
The instance member 'handlePress' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

Is there a way to provide a simple, reusable configuration for widgets where a specific widget type is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use simple configuration, you can use the following way.

In case of extracting an `AppBar`, what I would do is I will create a function that returns AppBar. I said this for `AppBar` only because it implements `PreferredSizeWidget`. So when it comes to extracting other widgets, I will always choose to create `Stateless/Stateful` widgets.

Here's the demo code of extracting an `AppBar`:

```js
getAppBar(String? title, void Function()? onPressed) {
  return AppBar(
    title: Text(title ?? "Demo title"),
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        onPressed: onPressed ?? () {},
        icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

You can add or remove the variables as per your choice but I use this approach only for extracting the **AppBar**.

Answer (score 0):

```
    AppBar projectAppBar(String title)     {
  return AppBar(
        backgroundColor:           ProjectColors.mainColor,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(title, style:         FontPath.bold21, textAlign:         TextAlign.center),
centerTitle: true,

                
          ),
  );
}
```

I always use like that